# What is the name of this realistic design style and where can I find tutorials for it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, style-identification

As a junior UX/UI designer I would like to be able to recreate this design technique (following imgs).

It's hard to describe but overall a sleek, usually "milky/grainy" and gradient brushed texture with buttons n sliders and its carved tracks (looks to me like there is intentional noise added). It really gives a professional and realistic feeling.

Does this style have a name and/or better, are there any tutorials available?

Thankee sai!

[image]

Google link below to see similar style:

https://www.google.se/search?q=photoshop+buttons&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:Cflta0izRFJ5IjjgtmDh9v4NpQiRG6Q6x-Rb_1lejMcvgJTTTD9xjKZar_1BQzluoS45pINOZOv1uO5tyvjUaxf4h1YCoSCeC2YOH2_1g2lERpnz3rTGzFyKhIJCJEbpDrH5FsRbzjLFbsf1vYqEgn-V6Mxy-AlNBExhRgrJNPPGioSCdMP3GMplqv8EXLUYUk5lRdGKhIJFDOW6hLjmkgRVT8ZgSu7xjEqEgk05k6_1W47m3BEM1Y7X4TIjaCoSCa-NRrF_1iHVgEVjVFxWz-zQE&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMz6Hz7bjWAhVsIpoKHZMQC6MQ9C8IHw&biw=2144&bih=869&dpr=0.9

Answer (score 2):

This looks like something I'd call 'photorealistic skeuomorphism' or a close variant. I think if you'd Google that term with 'tutorial' appended, you'd be bound to find something.

Comment: Oooh that's a tounge twister almost haha...but nonetheless correct! Thank you so much!! A whole new world just opened up! :D

Comment: Yeah me too. If the design above, knobs and dials are interactive then it's photorealistic skeuomorphism. If its static its just photo realistic. Here's a good debate about photorealistic skeuomorphism:  http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2012/11/scott_forstall_fired_skeumorphism_the_design_concept_that_s_tearing_apple.html